# Invalid pointer operation when freeing TStreamAdapter

Tags: com, c++builder

Can anyone clarify why do I get "Invalid pointer operation" when I attempt to delete `TStreamAdapter`? Or... how to properly free the memory from `TStreamAdapter`? It works, if I remove the `delete` but that causes a memory leak. Even if I use boost::scoped_ptr it also fails with the same error.

Note: I also tried initializing `TStreamAdapter` with `soOwned` value, same error.

The code:

```cpp
HRESULT LoadFromStr(TWebBrowser* WB, const UnicodeString& HTML)
{
if (!WB->Document)
    {
    WB->Navigate("about:blank");
    while (!WB->Document) { Application->ProcessMessages(); }
    }

DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = WB->Document;

if (diDoc)
    {
    boost::scoped_ptr<TMemoryStream> ms(new TMemoryStream);

        {
        boost::scoped_ptr<TStringList> sl(new TStringList);
        sl->Text = HTML;
        sl->SaveToStream(ms.get(), TEncoding::Unicode);
        ms->Position = 0;
        }

    DelphiInterface<IPersistStreamInit> diPSI;

    if (SUCCEEDED(diDoc->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistStreamInit, (void**)&diPSI)) && diPSI)
        {
        TStreamAdapter* sa = new TStreamAdapter(ms.get(), soReference);
        diPSI->Load(*sa);
        delete sa;  // <-- invalid pointer operation here???

        // UPDATED (solution) - instead of the above!!!
        // DelphiInterface<IStream> sa(*(new TStreamAdapter(ms.get(), soReference)));
        // diPSI->Load(sa);
        // DelphiInterface is automatically freed on function end


        return S_OK;
        }
    }

return E_FAIL;
}
```

Update: I found the solution here - http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread743255.html

The solution is to use
`_di_IStream sa(*(new TStreamAdapter(ms.get(), soReference)));`
or...
`DelphiInterface<IStream> sa(*(new TStreamAdapter(ms.get(), soReference)));`

As it will automatically free the IStream once it is out of scope. At least it should - is there a possible memory leak here? (CodeGuard did not detect any memory leaks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TStreamAdapter` is a `TInterfacedObject` descendant, which implements reference counting semantics. You are not supposed to `delete` it at all, you need to let reference counting free the object when it is no longer being referenced by anyone.

Using `_di_IStream` (which is just an alias for `DelphiInterface<IStream>`) is the correct way to automate that with a smart pointer.  `TComInterface<IStream>` and `CComPtr<IStream>` would also work, too.

Comment: Glad it was you who made the reply - Thanks - because I wish this one http://www.delphigroups.info/3/1/174612.html could be corrected as well (guess where the idea to delete the `TStreamAdapter*` came from).